# Jenkins Tomcat Ubuntu - hudson/WebAppMain : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-14.04, jenkins, tomcat7

The title sums the setup.

I know the Error means the Java versions does not match, between the one tomcat is using and the one Jenkins is compiled.

If I run `java -version` I get: `java version "1.7.0_80"`

If I run `javac -version` I get: `1.7.0_80`

I do have other Java installation on the system which are there for other projects so I can't remove them, like Java 6, and 8.

My Environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME == /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
CATALINA_HOME == EMPTY
JENKINS_HOME == ~/.jenkins
```

=== UPDATE ===

I've removed the openjdk6 that was previously installed, and now I get another Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript.run(GroovyHookScript.java:63)
    at hudson.util.BootFailure.publish(BootFailure.java:43)
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

=== UPDATE ===

When checking in the sources I find [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/util/groovy/GroovyHookScript.java) at line 63, and then [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/model/Jenkins.java) lines 682 & 762, it seems that Jenkins or j.servletContext is not initialized...

What am I doing wrong?

If there are missing details, let me know I'll add to the question.